# OntoText GraphDb OAuth2 login in using Azure

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, graphdb

I am trying to integrate AzuerAD OAuth authentication with graph-db following the instructions https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/access-control.html and can't understand the reason it is failing.

My `graphdb.properties` config is as follows:

```
graphdb.auth.methods = basic, gdb, openid
graphdb.auth.openid.issuer = https://login.microsoftonline.com
graphdb.auth.openid.client_id = 596251be-....from AD
graphdb.auth.openid.username_claim = email
graphdb.auth.openid.auth_flow = code
graphdb.auth.openid.token_type = access
```

Also had failed attempted with:

```
graphdb.auth.openid.issuer = https://login.microsoftonline.com/da0adc10-UUID/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

I can successfully login to:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/da0adc10-UUID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=596251be-from-AD&scope=openid&response_type=code`. It's a success because after signing it prompts me with a reminder for a setting.

However, when the redirection happens to `http://localhost:7200/login`, it fails. (Also tried setting redirect uri to `http://localhost:7200/login` which was also a failure).

Failure (seen on Network tab of browser):

```
http://localhost:7200/login?code=0.AUIAENwK2txuskGrQ9UmuxHFYL5RYlkgP---lenghty-stuff---&session_state=dd3f6443-some-string

...eventually...

Request URL: http://localhost:7200/rest/security/authenticatedUser
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401
```

Can you provide any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

The redirect URL should be the basic URL of the GraphDB server, which in your case seems to be http://localhost:7200/. It won't work with http://localhost:7200/login.

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/5682252/pavel-mihaylov
I made the change, but after logging in, I now get a `401` for `https://login.windows.net/da0adc10-6edc-xxx/oauth2/token` with the response payload of: `"error": "invalid_client",  "error_description": "AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'...",  ..., "error_uri": "https://login.windows.net/error?code=7000218"}`

I am confused now, because there's no where to specify `client_secret` in `graphdb.properties`

Comment: If I manually issue the POST adding `client_secret`, i do get a Bearer token back.
I have tried setting `graphdb.auth.openid.authorize_parameters=client_secret=xxxx` but that didn't get picked up